# How to identify where is called my component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I got a component that is getting informations from a page, or an app, that instantiates it ;

Could you help me understanding how to identify who / where is called the component ?

It should be easy, but I'm lost there..

Comment: Might wanna look into dependency API : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_metadata_metadatacomponentdependency.htm

Comment: @Alexis MASSON, its not clear what you are looking to get contextually from your component

Answer (score 1):

There are few possibilities.

1. Your component is getting initialized by listening to an application event.
2. Your component is getting initialized from its parent. It might be the child and you are looking to find who is/are the parent.
3. Your component might be getting initialized from listening to the platform event.

So, One way is definately to use Lightning inspector and check the component dependency.

Another way is to take all your org code to a local system and use tools like the sublime/VS Code. To find out the references for your component name.